# Slicing Dataframe: 2400 rows into 100 columns each of 24 rows

Tags: pandas

I am new to pandas. I was wondering if anyone new a quick way to slice a dataframe such that. Input every 24 rows as a new column. The data I have is just one long stream of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We using [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

```
pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.values, (24, 100)))
```

Comment: Reshape method is convenient too, `df.values.reshape(24, 100)`.

Comment: @miradulo ah ,forget this beauty :-)